# add text to another frame

Tags: java, swing

how can i add text "shutdown " to textfield1 
and exit frame5 when i press button22 in frame4 ????

```
  JButton jButton22 = new JButton();
  JButton jButton23 = new JButton();
  JButton jButton24 = new JButton();

  public Frame4() {
    try {
      jbInit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  private void jbInit() throws Exception {
    titledBorder1 = new TitledBorder("");
   border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(164, 225, 164),2);
    border2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(164, 225, 164),2);
    border3 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(94, 85, 50),2);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(63, 138, 232));
    this.setSize(new Dimension(400, 345));
this.setLocation(150,150);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(211, 229, 250));
    jPanel1.setBorder(border3);
    jPanel1.setBounds(new Rectangle(4, 47, 389, 193));
    jPanel1.setLayout(null);
    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 30));
    jLabel1.setForeground(new Color(255, 137, 27));
    jLabel1.setAlignmentY((float) 0.5);
    jLabel1.setText("       server side ®™");
    jLabel1.setBounds(new Rectangle(-44, 0, 314, 54));
    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 15));
    jLabel2.setForeground(new Color(60, 193, 60));
    jLabel2.setText("status is connected");
    jLabel2.setBounds(new Rectangle(107, 11, 165, 31));
    jLabel4.setBounds(new Rectangle(252, 160, 124, 42));
    jButton20.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButton20_actionPerformed(e);
      }
    });

    jButton22.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButton22_actionPerformed(e);

      }
    });

    jButton23.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButton23_actionPerformed(e);
      }
    });

    jButton24.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButton24_actionPerformed(e);
      }
    });


  void jButton20_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
new Frame3().setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
  }
  void jButton21_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
System.exit(0);
  }
  void jButton22_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    new Frame5().setVisible(true);


this.setVisible(false);
  }
  void jButton23_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    new Frame5().setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
  }
  void jButton24_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    new Frame5().setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format code by selecting it and pressing CTRL+K. Use the preview.

Comment: please try to use meaningful variables name

Comment: autogenerated... Hate it... Ask your IDE

Comment: i cant add text to textfield in frame5 when i press button22 in frame4

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit confusing.
I think your question is to change the text of a textfield of another frame from the current frame. 
If it is so, then you can do it simply by using functions. For example,
If you have two frames frame4 and frame5, the frame4 contains a button (say button4) and frame5 contains a textfield (say jtextfield).

You want to change the text of jtextfield in frame5 when you click the button4 in frame4.
Write a function in frame5 like,

> public void change(String text) {
>   
> jtextfield.setText(text) 
>   
> }

Then for changing the text from frame4, just call that function "change" .ie,

> frame5 f=new frame5();
>   f.change("Shutdown");
>   
>   where "shutdown" is the text you want to add.